# How to select 1000 customers who were the first to gain 1000 bonus points for purchases in categories "Taxi" and "Books"? (SQLite)

Tags: sql, sqlite, sum, inner-join, where-clause

The BONUS table has attributes: client_id, bonus_date, the number of accrued bonuses (bonus_cnt), mcc code of the transaction for which added bonuses (mcc_code). The MCC_CATEGORIES table is a mcc code reference.
Attributes:
mcc-code (mcc_code), category (for example, supermarkets, transport, pharmacies, etc., mcc_category)

How to select 1000 customers who were the first to gain 1000 bonus points for purchases in
categories "Taxi" and "Books"?

BONUS table looks like:

```
CLIENT_ID  BONUS_DATE  BONUS_CNT  MCC_CODE
1121       2020-01-02  23         5432
3421       2020-04-15  7          654
...
```

MCC_CATEGORIES table looks like:

```
MCC_CODE   MCC_CATEGORY
5432       Taxi
3532       Music
...
```

Comment: Do you mean separately in each category?  In either category?  Or combined between the two categories?

Answer (score 0):

I would use window functions and aggregation: first join the tables and compute the running sum of bonus per user and category. Then aggregate by user and category, and get the date when they reached a bonus of 1000. Finally, compute the date when each user reached the target on both categories, order by that, and limit:

```
select client_id, max(bonus_date) bonus_date
from (
    select client_id, mcc_category, min(bonus_date) bonus_date
    from (
        select b.client_id, b.bonus_date, c.mcc_category, 
            sum(bonus_cnt) over(partition by b.client_id, c.mcc_category order by b.bonus_date) sum_bonus
        from bonus b
        inner join mcc_categories c on c.mcc_code = b.mcc_code
        where mcc_category in ('Taxi', 'Books')
    ) t
    where sum_bonus >= 1000
    group by client_id, mcc_category
) t
group by client_id
having count(*) = 2
order by bonus_date
limit 1000
```

Window functions are available in SQLite starting version 3.25.

Answer (score 0):

> How to select 1000 customers who were the first to gain 1000 bonus points for purchases in categories "Taxi" and "Books"?

I am guessing you want to combine the bonuses for the two categories together.  If so:

```
select client_id, min(bonus_date) as min_bonus_date
from (select b.client_id, b.bonus_date, b.bonus_cnt,
             sum(b.bonus_cnt) over (partition by b.client_id order by b.bonus_date) as running_bonus_cnt
      from bonus b join
           mcc_categories c
           on c.mcc_code = b.mcc_code
      where mcc_category in ('Taxi', 'Books')
     ) bc
 where running_bonus_cnt >= 1000 and
       running_bonus_cnt - bonus_cnt < 1000
group by client_id
order by min_bonus_date
limit 1000;
```

Note how this works.  The subquery calculates the running bonus amount.  The `where` clause then gets the one row where the bonus count first exceeds 1000.

The rest is just aggregation.